# An elementary number theory as basis problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you find all $a,b \in \Bbb N$ such that $$a b^2 + b + 7 \mid a^2 b  + a + b$$.
I think $a = 7 t^2$ ,$b = 7 t$ and $a =1 $ or $19$ and $b = 19$ or $1$ are all solutions. Please help me to prove it and find other solutions.
If $a = 7 t^2$ and $b = 7 t$ then $7^3 t^4 + 7 t + 7 \mid 7^3 t^5 + 7 t^3 + 7 t = t (7^3 t^4 + 7 t + 7)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For all "$a,b \in \Bbb N $ such that $ ab^2+b+7|a^2b+a+b$" what?

Comment: I think you mean *find* all such $a,b$, not "prove" them.

Comment: @GitGud, the question's there: "s.t. the left expressions **divides** the right one"

Comment: @agustin I see by your other questions that you're not in the habit of accepting answers. Please consider accepting answers whenever you get at least one good answer.

Comment: What do you mean "and $a=1$ or $19$ and $b=19$ or $1$ are all solution"? ($a=1,b=19$) or ($a=19,b=1$) are not solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(ab^2+b+7) \mid [a(ab^2+b+7)-b(a^2b+a+b)]=7a-b^2$.

If $b \geq 3$, then we have $|ab^2+b+7|=ab^2+b+7 \geq b^2+b+7>b^2-7a$ and $|ab^2+b+7|=ab^2+b+7 \geq 9a+10>7a-b^2$.

Thus $|7a-b^2|<|ab^2+b+7|$, so $7a-b^2=0$. Clearly $7 \mid b$, so write $b=7t, t \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, so $a=7t^2$. This clearly works.

If $b=1$, $(a+8) \mid (7a-1)$, so $(a+8) \mid [7(a+8)-(7a-1)]=57$. Thus $a=11, 49$, which work.

If $b=2$, $(4a+9) \mid (7a-4)$, so $(4a+9) \mid [7(4a+9)-4(7a-4)]=79$, giving no solutions.

Thus all solutions are given by $(a, b)=(7t^2, 7t), (11, 1)$.